# Running an old binary, libstdc++.so.5 is missing, set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, what to try next?

Tags: c++, libstdc++

I received a copy of a binary that throws an error upon execution:

```
"error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

(Unfortunately, I can't get the original source code since the original developer moved to a different country and discontinued this project. I only know that it was C++ code that was developed around 2008)

My suspicion was that it just can't locate the `libstdc++.so.5`, thus, I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.5:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, however, the same problem still persists.

I read through some related posts, but I couldn't find a good answer for this particular case. Let's assume that this is a 32-bit application that is not compatible to my `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.5`, would it still throw the same

```
"error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

Furthermore, if I execute

```
ldd myapplication
```

I get

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x002f0000)
libstdc++.so.5 => not found
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x0099d000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00e62000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00639000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00617000)
```

Comment: In Linux, the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a colon-separated set of directories where libraries should be searched for first, before the standard set of directories

Comment: You are trying to specify a **file** not a directory in there

Comment: I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, where `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.5` is a library that exists on this machine, but this still doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: However,  I now get an "error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64", guess this is a 32 vs. 64 bit issue then

Comment: Are you running the program on a 32 bit or 64 bit machine?

Comment: May be one binary is 32 bit binary. You may check "$file binary_executable"  and "$file library_file " to see if any of them is ELF 32 bit binary.

Comment: Thanks, as it turns out, it's a 32 bit bin `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped`

Comment: I will have to install the respective 32bit lib then